# How to extract changesets(or commits) between last two tags in mercurial using python script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mercurial, dvcs

I have written following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

os.system('hg tags > tags.txt')

file = 'tags.txt'

path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file)

fp = open(path)

for i, line in enumerate(fp):

    if i == 1:

    latestTagLine = line`      

    elif i == 2:

        previousTagLine = line    

    elif i > 4:

        break

fp.close()

revLatestTag = latestTagLine.split(':')

l = revLatestTag[0].split(' ')

revPreviousTag = previousTagLine.split(':')

p = revPreviousTag[0].split(' ')

command = 'hg log -r {}:{} > diff.txt'.format(l[-1],p[-1])

os.system(command)
```

Is there any way in which i don't have to parse the output of "hg tags' command to get the revision numbers ?

Is there any pythonic way to do this ?

o/p of "hg tags" command:

tip                         523:e317b6828206

TOOL_1.4                    522:5bb1197f2e36

TOOL_1.3                    515:7362c0effe40

TOOL_1.1                    406:33379f244971

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've said in answers before, when playing with Mercurial [revsets are your friend](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets). That said, what you want doesn't appear to be covered by the revset documentation, but is mentioned in the help for the [log](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/log) command.

In your code you appear to be wanting a `diff` of what has changed between the "newest" two tags, and the following should do the job for you:

```
hg diff -r "last(tagged(),2)"
```

I realise you're working in Python, but the above command will do the grunt work, and your Python code can focus on less menial tasks.  The important part is the bit in the quotes, which I'll explain.

`tagged()` is a list of all revisions that are tagged - it should refer to the same revisions as `hg tags`, however it will only list each revision once, whereas `hg tags` will show multiple tags for a single revision, if that's the case.

`last(set,[n])` filters the set (in this case the tagged sets) to show the last `n` items (`n` is 1 if omitted).

The result of this is a revset that contains the last two tagged changes, which in the example above we pass into `hg diff`.

---

**Update:** OK, I was thrown by the `diff` in your Python.  On reading again, it looks like you want basically the `log` output between the last two tags?  Using revsets this becomes a little more convoluted, but using the above knowledge you can create a revset like so:

```
hg log -r "last(tagged(),2):last(tagged())"
```

We're effectively picking the last two tags, and the last one tag (!!) and performing a log of all inclusive sets between them.  The `log` output can be tweaked with `--template`, as LazyBadger has shown in his answer.  I would go for a simplistic `--template "{node}\t{tags}\n"`, but have a look [here](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/templates) for more information on the fun you can have.

Comment: i dont want the diff between the two TAGS, i only want the changesets of those diffs

Comment: Do you mean you want the hashes/IDs of the changesets, or the list of files that are different between the two? Sorry, my Python is a little rusty :)

Comment: i want IDs of the changesets between the two TAGS

Comment: FYI last(tagged(),2) == last(tagged()) by definition

Comment: @LazyBadger: The default value of `n` in `last` is 1, not 2, so they're not the same.

Comment: @icabod - **result** of last() and last(,2) will be the same - last

Comment: @LazyBadger: as per the documentation, `last(set,[n])` gives the last `n` members of set, defaulting to 1. `last(set,2)` returns a set of two items.

Comment: @icabod - ok... once more. last(set,2) IS SET of 2 changests, it can not be start of range

Comment: @icabod - while for rangeset you must define STARTSET:ENDSET

Comment: @icabod I reversed the arguments like this hg log -r "last(tagged():last(tagged(),2))" to get reversed o/p, but it is giving only changeset of last TAG. why?

Comment: @Patrick: That's _actually_ due to what Lazy Badger is saying... it works the way 'round I mention (despite protestations to the contrary), so to get a reversed output you can wrap the whole thing in a `reverse(...)`. If this is something you plan to do often, consider making a `revsetalias` in your configs.

Answer (score 1):

- As revset's identifier in `hg log -r`, you can use *any* identity, which uniquely identifies the changeset - tag name is OK

With

```
>hg tags
tip                             1126:cb4dccc90ff1
1.6                             1104:7d47a0f73135
...
```

log in form

```
>hg log -r "1.6"
changeset:   1104:7d47a0f73135
tag:         1.6
...
```

will find correct changeset, as you can see

- Using revsets, you can eliminate variables from the resulting command totally

Step-by-step

All tags: `hg log -r "tag()"`

Latest tag: `hg log -r "last(tag())"`

Penultimate tag: `hg log -r "first(last(tag(),2)))"` (maybe `min()` instead of `first()` in some cases)

Final command becomes

`hg log -r "((first(last(tag(),2))):(last(tag())))"`

for used it tests hgsubversion repository polished version of log

```
hg log -r "((first(last(tag(),2))):(last(tag())))" --template "changeset: {node|short}\n{if(tags, 'Tag: {tags}\n')}\n"
```

produced such output (middle-noise skipped)

```
changeset: d0f3a5c2cb56
Tag: 1.5.1

changeset: b5b1fce26f1f

...

changeset: 6e1dbf6cbc92

changeset: 7d47a0f73135
Tag: 1.6
```

**FIX: for redundant parentheses and missing quotes**

```
hg log -r "first(last(tag(),2)):last(tag())" ...
```

Comment: all your command giving me error : -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: @Patrick - use -r `"(all revset here)"` form (or `'()'`, can't recall rules for *sh-shells)

Comment: i didn't understood ur comment, i ran your command   hg log -r (last("tag()")) in the terminal and got error

Comment: @Patrick - formally revset equation must be wrapped into quotes (or double quotes): `hg log -r "last('tag()')"` and I used extra pair of parentheses (automatically, habitually), not needed around outer predicate

Comment: hg log -r "((first(last(tag(),2))):(last(tag())))" , this worked means i have to add " before and after () outermost, can u please update ur answer according to this, so i can accept ur answer

Comment: @Patrick - try hg log -r "last(tag())" - `hg help revsets` tells: "Identifiers such as branch names may need quoting with single or double
    quotes if they contain characters like "-" or if they match one of the
    predefined predicates." my overusage of quotes is obvious mistake

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47961/discussion-between-patrick-and-lazy-badger)